# Using a dataframe to filter a dataframe - purrr::map and dplyr::filter?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have dataframe that has a set of parameters (`params`) I'd like to filter a dataframe with data in (`df`), thereby creating multiple subsets of `df`.

My querys are in:

```
params <- expand.grid(category = c("Big","Small"),
                      Year = c(2017,2018,2019),
                      Month = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"))
```

My dataframe is:

```
df <- data.frame(category =c("Foo", "Bah", "Foo", "Foo", "Bah", "Bah", "Bah", "Foo", "Foo", "Bah"),
                 year = c(2017, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2019),
                 month =c("Jan","Feb","Feb","Jan","Nov","Apr","Nov","Jan","May","May"))
```

I wondered if this could be done via `purrr::map2` but I see that it only works on vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

```
purrr::pmap(params, ~dplyr::filter(df,category == ..1, year == ..2, month == ..3))
```

which in base R, can be written with `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y, z) subset(df, category == x & year == y & month == z), 
                      params$category, params$Year, params$Month)
```

Comment: Yes! I've never come across the use of "..1" etc for predicates. When I run this i get a list of list. Any thoughts on how to change each result into a dataframe?

Comment: Use `pmap_df`, `purrr::pmap_df(params, ~dplyr::filter(df,category == ..1, year == ..2, month == ..3))`